# Rxjs Subject/Observable subscribe Array of list

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one easy question.
I have service `DataStorageServiceService` and in this service I have `shopCartProtudct = new Subject<ProductModel[]>();`.
I have component `SingleProductComponent` and from this component I want sent data sent data in to `shopCartProtudct` but like array, I want to interact with interact `shopCartProtudct` like basic array, than means, I want to store data and delete. This is posible?

Comment: You need functions in your service that you can call to do the interaction for you.

Comment: Is this ok to create single array and interact with him, and this array send in to the `shopCartProtudct `?

Comment: I can not do like with method `shop(product:ProductModel){
  this.shopCartProtudct.next(product);
}`

Comment: @JaoMing it's because subject is expecting an array of ProductModel and you are trying to send single product object.

Comment: @JaoMing change new Subject<ProductModel[]>(); to new Subject<ProductModel>();

Answer (score 2):

You are likely looking for a Service implementation like this:
Note: Untested code, consider it a pseudo code almost.

```
export class DataStorageService {

    //A subject that you can subscribe on
    shopCardProduct = new Subject<ProductModel[]>();

    //array behind the products in the cart
    products : ProductModel[] = new Array<ProductModel>() ;

    constructor(){
        this.shopCardProduct = new BehaviorSubject<ProductModel>(new Array<ProductModel>())
    }

    shop(product: ProductModel){
        this.products.push(product);
        this.shopCardProduct.next(this.products);
    }

    getCart(): Subject<ProductModel[]> {
        return this.shopCardProduct;
    }

}
```